# App Store App analytics metrics and dimensions - Understand how "Deletions" is calculated?

Tags: ios, uninstallation, appsflyer

App Store shares "Deletions" [https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/itc21781223f] counts for the app. We internally also track the same via Sending a silent push notification to the app to track whether the user has uninstalled the app.

In the past 30-60 days what we are seeing is a large delta (2x) higher "deletions" being reported  by the App store as compared to our internal silent push notification approach.

Out internal hypothesis is that, the count different would be due to :

1. App Store counting users who don't opt-in for push notifications on their iOS devices.
2. App store not requiring user to actually launch the App to count install / deletion ( granted this would be a smaller number).

We also use Appsflyer as a third party tool which is reporting a similar delta.

In June - July we haven't seen any variation, August onwards is when we see the variation. We also extrapolate the counts since App store shares the percentage of user have opted-in to share  their data.

Any insights or experience around this would be helpful so that we be doubly sure that there is nothing wrong with the app (We haven't seen a spike in Crashes or changed anything related to credentials on our end).

Comment: I do the exact same for my app and have likewise noticed the discrepancy. Would love an answer as well as I'm starting to believe it makes sense to just ignore the Deletions metric in the app store entirely. Though, if Deletions are this wrong, what about the other stats?